Delete sames values in 2d array
I would like to delete same values in this 2d array :
var array = [["ok",1],["non ok",2],["ok",1],["ok",3],["non ok",2],["ok",4]];

The result expected ll be :
[["ok",1],["non ok",2],["ok",3],["ok",4]];

Can you help me with this "easy" thing for others developpers but not for me...
I tried to search in google but i don't find anything who can help me

In your situation, how about the following sample script?
Sample script:


// This is from your question.
const array = [["ok", 1], ["non ok", 2], ["ok", 1], ["ok", 3], ["non ok", 2], ["ok", 4]];

const res = [...array.reduce((m, r) => {
  const k = r.join("");
  if (!m.has(k)) {
    m.set(k, r);
  }
  return m;
}, new Map()).values()];
console.log(res); // [ [ 'ok', 1 ], [ 'non ok', 2 ], [ 'ok', 3 ], [ 'ok', 4 ] ]



When this script is run, res is [ [ 'ok', 1 ], [ 'non ok', 2 ], [ 'ok', 3 ], [ 'ok', 4 ] ].
References:

reduce()
Map

